# Trying to do a very basic login page using CSHTML but I can't get my if statement to work correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, webmatrix

```
@{

    Page.Title = "Log in";

    // Generate page variables
    var db = Database.Open("calcinema");
    var email = "";
    var password = "";
    var getAcc = db.Query("SELECT * FROM Account;");

    if (IsPost && Validation.IsValid()) {
        email = @Request.Form["email"];
        password = @Request.Form["password"];}

        foreach (var a in getAcc) {

            if (email == a.Email && password == a.Password){
                 Response.Redirect("~/Browse.cshtml");}
     }            
}

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
<table border="0" align="center">
    <tr>
    <td>
        <form name="login" action="" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">  
        <label for="email">Email</label>  
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="yourname@email.com" required value = "@Request.Form["email"]"> 
        <label for="password">Password</label>  
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required value = "@Request.Form["password"]">  
        <input type="submit" value="Login"> 
        </form>  
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

The page loads but nothing happens regardless of whether or not the email and password is valid. It just takes the input and then returns me to the login page with the text fields empty as opposed to redirecting me to the Browse.cshtml page.

Comment: Have you tried to debug and see the result obtained in `getAcc`?

Comment: @RKS I'm not aware of a WebMatrix debugger, is there one?

Comment: 1. That block of code should go in your controller. 2. Your form method should be a POST because it is changing server state. 3. Please do not store passwords in plain text.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is your form's method. You have chosen `GET` which passes the form values in the QueryString. You are looking in the `Request.Form` collection, but the values aren't there. Change the method to `POST`.

You also need to make sure you query the database properly and return the result to be examined by your code. There are also other issue in that you cannot set the value of an `input type=password` and the `required` attribute does not work with server-side validation.

Here's some code that will work, but I recommend you spend some time with the [tutorials here](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials) and learn the basics of Web Pages. It's a great framework but does require a bit of application to learn properly.

```
@{
    Page.Title = "Log in";
    if (IsPost && Validation.IsValid()) {
        var email = Request.Form["email"];
        var password = Request.Form["password"];
        var db = Database.Open("calcinema");
        var result = db.QueryValue("SELECT Count(*) FROM Account WHERE Email = @0 AND Password = @1", email, password);
        if (result > 0){
            Response.Redirect("~/Browse.cshtml");
         }            
    }
}
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <title></title>
        </head>
        <body>
    <table border="0" align="center">
        <tr>
        <td>
            <form name="login" action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">  
            <label for="email">Email</label>  
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="yourname@email.com" required value = "@Request.Form["email"]"> 
            <label for="password">Password</label>  
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>  
            <input type="submit" value="Login"> 
            </form>  
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is likely this:

```
 email = @Request.Form["email"];
 password = @Request.Form["password"];
```

You don't need to prefix `Request` with an ampersand since you're already in server-side code:

```
 email = Request.Form["email"];
 password = Request.Form["password"];
```

You really shouldn't be doing this. You should pass those values as parameters to your SQL command then see if there is a match:

```
 var result = db.QueryValue("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Account WHERE email = @0 AND password = @1", email, password);
```

And of course, the various security considerations about SSL, plain-text password and SQL injection safeguards apply.

Comment: Ah yes, that's right. I've fixed that now but that didn't make the page work

Comment: Please use SQL parameters so you don't become a victim of SQL Injection

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the if clause statement that you're providing. The statement would never be true with this HTML form's method. You nee to change it.

Have a look

```
if (IsPost && Validation.IsValid()) {
    email = @Request.Form["email"];
    password = @Request.Form["password"];
}

foreach (var a in getAcc) {

   if (email == a.Email && password == a.Password) {
      Response.Redirect("~/Browse.cshtml");
   }
}
```

You need to execute the `@Request.Form["email"]` code only if the request if `POST`, but your form is set to `method="get"` which would always skip the IF block.

And since the if block is skipped, your code would always have a value of empty string or the initial value that the email and password both had. Thus, the second if block would also not execute and won't redirect you to the **Browse.cshtml** page.